# Convertin mysql varchar to number then adding

Tags: mysql

i have a query with an inner select :

```
(SELECT SUM(marketing_fee) FROM answer WHERE  user_id = m.id AND submit_dt between '2017-02-08 23:59:00' and '2017-02-15 23:59:00') as bookedamount,
```

the problem is that marketing_fee is a string and can be null, 'null' on any number (but as a string structure).

Is there a way to do a conversion in my select and add them together to get a single total figure that excludes the blanks and nulls?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you show some data from `marketing_fee` column, and desired result?

Comment: It can either be null, have nothing in it at all or have a number in (650, 1000, 250) but i want to get the sum of all the ones that arnt null or blank

Comment: @Gaz - NULL and blank  anyway are not included / calculated by `SUM` function. So, what is the problem?

Comment: Yes, SUM should work in this case.

Comment: the field is a varchar not an int. a blank field is not the same as a DB NULL

Comment: Do you have wrong result with it?

Comment: If you sum emprty string `''`, `NULL` and `3`, result will be `3`

Comment: SUM() ignores NULLs. If the string is literally `'NULL'` or any other string of non-numeric characters, then its implicit integer value is zero, so has no effect on SUM().

Comment: Seemsto be adding the amount of rows (eg 5) though there are 5 rows with margeting_fee of 500, 750,200,700,300 for eg

Comment: I'm beginning to suspect that you the code you posted is not the code you're running. It would function like a count if you had a boolean expression inside the sum function, like `SUM(marketing_fee is not null)` or something like that. Because in MySQL boolean expressions evaluate to the integers 1 or 0, and a SUM() of 1's is equal to a count.

Comment: This is the full query :

ELECT m.username,
       (select count(*) from status_history where insertedby = m.username and status = 'booked' and date between '2017-02-08 23:59:00' and '2017-02-15 23:59:00') unitsbooked,
       
        (SELECT SUM(TRIM(IFNULL(marketing_fee, 0)) <> '') FROM answer WHERE  user_id = m.id AND submit_dt between '2017-02-08 23:59:00' and '2017-02-15 23:59:00') as bookedamount,

         (SELECT update_dt 
          FROM location
         WHERE location.user_id = m.id) lastseen
   FROM user m 
            where m.active is null

Comment: Its returning the user id haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN marketing_fee is NULL THEN 0 ELSE CONVERT(marketing_fee, INTEGER)) FROM answer WHERE  user_id = m.id AND submit_dt between '2017-02-08 23:59:00' and '2017-02-15 23:59:00') as bookedamount
```

Here's the documentation;

- [CONVERT](http://sql.sh/fonctions/convert)
- [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)

**EDIT 1:**

Try this simpler answer:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN marketing_fee is NULL OR marketing_fee = '' THEN 0 ELSE marketing_fee) as bookedamount
FROM answer
WHERE user_id = m.id
AND submit_dt between '2017-02-08 23:59:00' and '2017-02-15 23:59:00';
```

Comment: Doesnt seem to like the syntax

Comment: Please could you assist me with one more part of the query? There is also 2 fields called 'EPC' and 'domesticepc', if either of them are 1 (varchar) then could it -175 from the marketing_fee for each one that has an EPC or domestic EPC(if both are 1 it should still only be-175 not -350